# Can I force gdb to step using hardware breakpoints?

Tags: gdb

I am debugging a remote target and it seems like the software breakpoints are not working, however hardware breakpoints do work.

I want to be able to use the stepi command - but gdb seems to insist on using software breakpoints.

Is there a way to force gdb to use hardware breakpoints for stepi?

The target is an ARM STM32 chip debugged through a blackmagic probe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to mark the memory region as read only which forces gdb to use hw breakpoints

I.e if my code is running on the addresses 0x8000000-0x8010000 i run

```
mem 0x8000000 0x8010000 ro
```